# How can I check if a point is on a line defined by two other points?

Tags: python, math

I'm writing a program in python that needs to determine if a point is on an infinite line formed by two  other points. I found many other questions asking about line segments, but I need an infinite line.

Comment: If the point is a solution to `y = mx + b`, then it's on the line.

Comment: Think back to your early math knowledge: `y= mx + b`. Using the line defined by the two points, solve for `m` and `b`. Then, if you substitute the `x` value from the point in question into your formula, the returned value of `y` should be *nearly identical* (you will likely be comparing floats, so `==` will not return `True`) to the value of `y` in the point in question.

Comment: This is a dumb question, but how do I get the mx + b from two points

Comment: `m` is the slope, which is the difference of the y-components over the difference of the x-components. `b` is the y-offset, and you get that when you plug in zero for `x`. As Kraigolas mentioned, you'll probably be comparing floating-point numbers, so you can use `math.isclose` to determine whether they are "similar enough". You can also tweak the threshold for how similar the numbers need to be.

Comment: `m` = slope so just take difference of y by difference of x,for 'b' fit a point into it.For more specific formulae you can look up any co-ordinate geometry book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
# positive when P is on the left of oriented line AB, 
# neutral when P lies on AB,
# negative when P is on the right of oriented line AB
def half_space(pX, pY, aX, aY, bX, bY):
    return (bX - aX)*(pY - aY) - (bY - aY)*(pX - aX)
```

Comment: so if this is 0, then the point is on the line?

Comment: Yes, but I'd recommend testing for some small positive epsilon in the absolute value instead, because, you know, floating point numbers and such. Make a grid out of them and then try to intersect lines with other lattice points, good luck :D

Comment: all my numbers are integers, so would I still need an epsilon value?

Comment: @Nailuj29 Yeah, if all inputs are integers, you can just test for zero.